# Merge 3 sql selects into one. return assosiative array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Currently I make 3 sql select queries to 3 different tables. Is it possible to merge into just one?

```
SELECT * FROM recomendados INNER JOIN carpas ON recomendados.fk_id = carpas.id
SELECT * FROM recomendados INNER JOIN sacos ON recomendados.fk_id = sacos.id
SELECT * FROM recomendados INNER JOIN colchon ON recomendados.fk_id = colchon.id
```

The php code to make the queries is like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM recomendados INNER JOIN carpas ON recomendados.fk_id = carpas.id";
$result = $conexion->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    return $row;
}
```

If possible I would like an assosiative array with the table name as the key.

Comment: Try UNION or UNION ALL between statemets (if tables have same data types).

Comment: Yes, this should be possible, but I think we need a little more info to know what kind of joins to use and how to fetch in PHP to get the array you want. Are there some specific columns you want to get from the other related tables? And can you show an example of what you want the output array to look like? (If you can add more info, please edit the question rather than putting it in comments.)

Comment: If you can't do the UNION then issue 3 queries and fetch like `$rows['carpas'] = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` with the different table names.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code::

```php
$tables = ['carpas': [], 'sacos': [], ...];
foreach ($table in $tables) {
  $result = $conn->query("SELECT ... INNER JOIN ${table} ON recommendados.id = ${table}.ud");
  $rows = $result->fetch_all(...);
  $tables[$table] = $rows;
}
print($tables["carpas"]); // dataset from *carpas*
// etc
```